# TransactionScope in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

Given below is my sample code. They are all synchronous call to service from client. My question here is, How my remote service will know about the call -> ts.Complete();

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    try
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        obj.UpdateData();
        ServiceReference2.Service1Client obj1 = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();
        obj1.UpdateData();
        ts.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ts.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I am using WSHttpbinding. My questions are:

1. Will WSHttpbinding and basicHttpBinding both support transactions?
2. During the "ts.Complete()" call, or during exceptions in client scope, will a request call happen to remote WCF service to make the transaction manager commit/rollback his job ?

Answer (score 3):

**Will WSHttpbinding and basicHttpBinding both support transactions?**

You need to use WSHttpBinding to use TransactionScope as a BasicHttpBinding doesn't support the required WS-* standards for transactions.

**During "ts.Complete()" call Or During exception in client scope, will a request call happen to remote wcf service to make the transaction manager commit/rollback his job**

The complete call doesn't guarantee everything is committed. This tells the transaction manager you are done. It is the complete call on the transaction owner that causes the transaction manager to inform all parties to commit or rollback. If it can't communicate with all parties, it will throw an exception.

So to answer the question, the complete call on child-participants (i.e. not the owner) don't cause a call to the transaction manager, but the complete call from the owner-participant does call the transaction manager, which will then attempt to commit.

Answer (score 1):

TransactionScope uses MSDTC :

> MSDTC is an acronym for Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator.
>   As the name says, MSDTC is a Windows service providing transaction
>   infrastructure for distributed systems. In this case, a transaction
>   means a general way of structuring the interactions between autonomous
>   agents in a distributed system. Each transaction is a state
>   transformation with four key properties - the ACID properties: Atomic
>   (all or nothing), Consistent (legal), Isolated (independent of
>   concurrent transactions) and Durable (once it happens, it cannot be
>   abrogated). There are different techniques that implement the ACID
>   properties but the most known one is two-phase commit.

You should start with this article : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/florinlazar/archive/2004/03/04/what-is-msdtc-and-why-do-i-need-to-care-about-it.aspx

Comment: I am asking how client will notify the remote server about the transaction scope? During "ts.Complete()" call?